# Glass Mapper Model too deep. Potential lazy loading loop exception after upgrading to version 4.3.4.196

Tags: glass-mapper

I updated the Glass Mapper version for our Sitecore 8.2 project from version 4.0.1.8 to version 4.3.4.196.

After upgrading Sitecore is still running, but our websites are throwing exceptions:

> Model too deep. Potential lazy loading loop

I added the `Cacheable` property to the Models and I also had the `Setting = SitecoreFieldSettings.DontLoadLazily` on the Fields from before the upgrade. But no result, it keeps throwing this error.

My model structure has not changed, anyone any idea what is going on? Or maybe that `ModelDepthCheck` can be disabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see the release notes for 4.3 which explain how to remove the depth check:
http://www.glass.lu/Blog/Release4-3

The depth check is designed to capture models where lazy loading is disabled but a loop might have been caused which would result in a stack overflow. However some models maybe deep enough anyway to cause the depth check to fire. Currently it is set to a depth of 8.

Comment: Ah yes, now I see it. I overlooked the factory.Remove<ModelDepthCheck> yesterday in the release notes. :(
Thanks